# Does the series $\sum\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> Does the series $\sum\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})$ diverge or converge?

I tried the comparison test. We have $\sin(n) \leq n$ for all natural numbers $n$, so $\sin(\frac{1}{n}) \leq \frac{1}{n}$, and $\sin^2(\frac{1}{n}) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Note that the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, so the series $\sum\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})$ converges by the comparison test.

What have I messed up on in my working and explanations?

Comment: $\sin(x)\le x$ is actually true for every non-negative real $x$ , but this has to be justified. We cannot simply replace $n$ by $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @AnneBauval I have already seen that but I wanted feedback on my answer. Mine looks like the top comment they did so I think I am correct but like Peter said I am unsure on how to justify the inequality which is why I have started my own post

Comment: @Peter I thought you could like for the limit $\frac{sinx}{x}$ you can replace the $x$ with $\frac{1}{x}$ for example

Comment: @NikitaMazepin Only if the limit is for $x\to 0$ and if we let tend $x$ to $\infty$ , if we replace it by $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @Peter Oh yes by a change of variables. I am allowed to state $sin(n) \leq n$ for all natural numbers $n$ if that helps, so all I need help with is justifying $sin(\frac{1}{n}) \leq \frac{1}{n}$ please

Comment: Your terminology is quite sloppy. It's not a **series** unless you write out the summation sign $\sum$.

Comment: @HansLundmark I wrote series in place of the summation sign

Comment: $\sin n\le n$ for natural numbers is of no use here. Your derivation "$\sin(n) \leq n$ for all natural numbers $n$, ***so*** $\sin(\frac{1}{n}) \leq \frac{1}{n}$" is wrong. Use [Prove $\sin(x)<x$, $\forall x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978616) or [how to strictly prove $\sin x<x$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125298), applied to $x=1/n.$

Comment: And about your previous answer to Hans Lundmark: you should not have written the word "series" "in place of" but "in addition to" the symbol $\sum.$ I correct it.

Comment: @AnneBauval okay thanks I will take a look